# htaccess RewriteRule with Parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to make a rewriterule.

I want to make it like this;
Surfer types

```
[HOST]/ttr/ttr4cmd/register/check_screenname?screenname=[PARAMETER]
```

Browser adress bar shows same adress,but surfer sees this page;

```
[HOST]/ttr/ttr4cmd/register/check_screenname.php?screenname=[PARAMETER]
```

So,i wrote a simple htaccess file by a generator like this;

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)screenname=($|&)
RewriteRule ^ttr/ttr4cmd/register/check_screenname$ /ttr/ttr4cmd/register/check_screenname.php?screenname=&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

But when i go to adress,it gives me 404 error and says

`ttr/ttr4cmd/register/check_screenname is not found.`

Please help me with this. Thank you :)

EDIT: I did it like this,and it worked. Thanks ^^

```
RewriteRule ^ttr/ttr4cmd/register/check_screenname?$ ttr/ttr4cmd/register/check_screenname.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need QSA http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

so for example

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*screenname.*
RewriteRule ^/ttr/ttr4cmd/register/check_screenname /ttr/ttr4cmd/register/check_screenname.php [QSA]
```

Here you can find a good intro intro mod_rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! But it still gives 404 error :/
`The requested URL /ttr/ttr4cmd/register/check_screenname was not found on this server.`

Comment: okay then please activate `trace1` as described here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging